# Is there bromide insufficiency and if so, how does it treated without causing bromism?

Tags: nutrition, minerals

I have read about mineral inefficiencies in humans such as iron insufficiency or zinc insufficiency and recently I learned on the use of bromine containing molecules ([bromides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bromide)) in different medical conditions and this brought me to wonder if a mineral insufficiency of bromide also occurs in humans and if it might cause some of the symptoms treated by the following substances:

- Mucolytic (bromhexine)
- antihistamine (brompheniramine maleate)
- anticonvulsant (sodium bromide, potassium bromide) although used primarily for dogs
- commonly used short term sleep regulators (brompheniramine Maleate, brotizolam)
- rarely used long term sleep regulators (sodium bromide, potassium bromide)
- [From wikipedia:](http://McCall%20AS,%20Cummings%20CF,%20Bhave%20G,%20Vanacore%20R,%20Page-McCaw%20A,%20Hudson%20BG%20(2014).%20%22Bromine%20Is%20an%20Essential%20Trace%20Element%20for%20Assembly%20of%20Collagen%20IV%20Scaffolds%20in%20Tissue%20Development%20and%20Architecture%22.%20Cell.) "According to one study, bromine (as bromide) is an essential cofactor in the peroxidasin catalysis of sulfilimine crosslinks in collagen IV. This post-translational modification occurs in all animals, and bromine is an essential trace element for humans."
- if bromelain enzyme contains bromide (I didn't find clear information weather yes or no) - as a possible digestive aid.

Yet, I understand that exposure to too much bromide can cause a severe poisoning named [bromism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bromism).

Is there a known condition of bromide insufficiency and if so, how does it treated without causing bromism?

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but this question is very unclear on what you are trying to ask. *"Is there a bromide insufficiency..."* **in who?** What makes you think there is?

Comment: @ChrisRogers, there is some evidence that bromine might be an essential nutrient *in humans.*

Comment: @Jan - So are we to assume this is a question of *"Is there a bromide insufficiency **in the general world population**"*? If so that needs to be clear, plus the question of why the OP thinks it's possible also needs to be addressed IMO.

Comment: @ChrisRogers, I'm about to answer that.

Comment: Hello to you too --- I tried to edit the question per comments; @Jan yes, I thought about adding this but I assumed direct quoting isn't good and that I don't have enough knowledge on this particular subject to write about it but given you checked the source and commented about it, I just copy pasted the passage to the question.

Comment: That's fine and is actually encouraged here, so we know exactly what we are talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently, it has been considered that bromine might be an essential nutrient for humans. This article: [Bromine is an essential trace element for assembly of collagen IV scaffolds in tissue development and architecture (Cell, 2014)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4144415/) says that:

- Bromine is essential for collagen synthesis in the human body
- Bromine deficiency resulting in a damage of intestinal lining has been observed in recipients of total parenteral nutrition (intravenous infusion of a mixture of nutrients, but lacking bromine).

Nowadays, when a nutrient deficiency is observed only in recipients of total parenteral nutrition, it usually means it is rare.

The **drugs** mentioned in the question are **not** intended to treat bromine deficiency. If such deficiency is discovered (by a blood test), it can be treated by bromine **supplements** *by a doctor.* Anyway, I strongly advise against using bromine supplements without a clear indication.

Bromelain is an enzyme found in pineapple and is used as a digestive aid; from its chemical formula on [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Bromelain#section=Structures) you can see that it does not contain bromine.

Origin of the word bromelain ([Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/bromelain)):

> 1890–95; apparently bromel(in) an earlier name for the enzyme
>   (Bromel(ia) a genus that formerly included the pineapple (see
>   bromeliad) + -in2) + (pap)ain

Comment: Hello Jan, regarding Bromelain in PubChem, please review a nice session I opened in Chemistry SE: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/124043/representation-of-bromelain-molecule-in-two-dimensional-diagram

Comment: @JohnDoea, OK, I see that PubChem does not show the entire bromelain molecule. I serached for the origin of the word bromelain (see at the end of the answer) and you can see it's not about bromine.

Comment: Oh yes, that particular detail was clear to me. Of course the answer was helpful for me and I upvoted.